# for loop vs std::for_each with lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Let's consider a template function written in C++11 which iterates over a container.
Please exclude from consideration the range loop syntax because it is not yet supported by the compiler I'm working with.

```
template <typename Container>
void DoSomething(const Container& i_container)
  {
  // Option #1
  for (auto it = std::begin(i_container); it != std::end(i_container); ++it)
    {
    // do something with *it
    }

  // Option #2
  std::for_each(std::begin(i_container), std::end(i_container), 
    [] (typename Container::const_reference element)
    {
    // do something with element
    });
  }
```

What are pros/cons of for loop vs `std::for_each` in terms of:

a) performance? (I don't expect any difference)

b) readability and maintainability?

Here I see many disadvantages of `for_each`. It wouldn't accept a c-style array while the loop would. The declaration of the lambda formal parameter is so verbose, not possible to use `auto` there. It is not possible to break out of `for_each`.

In pre- C++11 days arguments against `for` were a need of specifying the type for the iterator (doesn't hold any more) and an easy possibility of mistyping the loop condition (I've never done such mistake in 10 years).

As a conclusion, my thoughts about `for_each` contradict the common opinion. What am I missing here?

Comment: `std::for_each` does work on c-style arrays.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The `typename Container::const_reference` won't.  OP should be using `std::iterator_traits<>::const_reference` instead.

Comment: @Andrey: you can't use `auto` in the lambda parameter, but you can certainly `typedef` if in the function body to make the lambda easier to read.

Comment: why not just run and time them yourself? or do some profiling with gprof? for the performance part

Comment: `for ( Container::const_reference r : container ) {`

Comment: Wouldn't something like decltype(*begin(i_container)) help for lambda case?

Comment: @André: for using iterator_traits, you have to get type of iterator. Possibly with decltype.

Comment: @pyCthon: I think the performance would be the same, so readability is the main factor which affects the choice

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: The range syntax is cool, but it is out of consideration until it's supported by my compiler

Comment: @AndréCaron: Isn't it still a lot of typing? Such long declarations make a code harder to read.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think there are some other differences not yet covered by the answers so far.

1. a `for_each` can accept *any* appropriate callable object, allowing one to 'recycle' the loop body for different for loops. For example (pseudo code)

   ```
   for( range_1 ) { lengthy_loop_body }    // many lines of code
   for( range_2 ) { lengthy_loop_body }    // the same many lines of code again
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   auto loop_body = some_lambda;           // many lines of code here only
   std::for_each( range_1 , loop_body );   // a single line of code
   std::for_each( range_2 , loop_body );   // another single line of code
   ```

   thus avoiding duplication and simplifying code maintenance. (Of course, in a funny mix of styles one could also use a similar approach with the `for` loop.)
2. another difference regards breaking out of the loop (with `break` or `return` in the `for` loop). As far as I know, in an `for_each` loop this can only be done by throwing an exception. For example

   ```
   for( range )
   {
     some code;
     if(condition_1) return x; // or break
     more code;
     if(condition_2) continue;
     yet more code;
   }
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   try {
     std::for_each( range , [] (const_reference x)
                   {
                     some code;
                     if(condition_1) throw x;
                     more code;
                     if(condition_2) return;
                     yet more code;
                   } );
   } catch(const_reference r) { return r; }
   ```

   with the same effects regarding calling of destructors for objects with scope of the loop body and the function body (around the loop).
3. the main benefit of `for_each` is, IMHO, that one can overload it for certain container types, when plain iteration is not as efficient. For example, consider a container that holds a linked list of data blocks, each block containing a contiguous array of elements, similar to (omitting irrelevant code)

   ```
   namespace my {
     template<typename data_type, unsigned block_size>
     struct Container
     {
       struct block
       {
         const block*NEXT;
         data_type DATA[block_size];
         block() : NEXT(0) {}
       } *HEAD;
     };
   }
   ```

   then an appropriate forward iterator for this type would require to check for the end of block at each increment and the comparison operator needs to compare both the block pointer and the index within each block (omitting irrelevant code):

   ```
   namespace my {
     template<typename data_type, unsigned block_size>
     struct Container
     {
       struct iterator
       {
         const block*B;
         unsigned I;
         iterator() = default;
         iterator&operator=(iterator const&) = default;
         iterator(const block*b, unsigned i) : B(b), I(i) {}
         iterator& operator++()
         {
           if(++I==block_size) { B=B->NEXT; I=0; }    // one comparison and branch
           return*this;
         }
         bool operator==(const iterator&i) const
         { return B==i.B && I==i.I; }                 // one or two comparisons
         bool operator!=(const iterator&i) const
         { return B!=i.B || I!=i.I; }                 // one or two comparisons
         const data_type& operator*() const
         { return B->DATA[I]; }
       };
       iterator begin() const
       { return iterator(HEAD,0); }
       iterator end() const
       { return iterator(0,0); }
     };
   }
   ```

   this type of iterator works correctly with `for` and `for_each`, for example

   ```
   my::Container<int,5> C;
   for(auto i=C.begin();
       i!=C.end();              // one or two comparisons here
       ++i)                     // one comparison here and a branch
     f(*i);
   ```

   but requires two to three comparisons per iteration as well as a branch. A more efficient way is to overload the `for_each()` function to loop on the block pointer and index separately:

   ```
   namespace my {
     template<typename data_type, int block_size, typename FuncOfDataType>
     FuncOfDataType&&
     for_each(typename my::Container<data_type,block_size>::iterator i,
              typename my::Container<data_type,block_size>::iterator const&e,
              FuncOfDataType f)
     {
       for(; i.B != e.B; i.B++,i.I=0)
         for(; i.I != block_size; i.I++)
           f(*i);
       for(; i.I != e.I; i.I++)
         f(*i);
       return std::move(f);
     }
   }
   using my::for_each;     // ensures that the appropriate
   using std::for_each;    // version of for_each() is used
   ```

   which requires only one comparison for most iterations and has no branches (note that branches can have a nasty impact on performance). Note that we don't need to define this in namespace `std` (which might be illegal), but can ensure that the correct version is used by appropriate `using` directives. This is equivalent to `using std::swap;` when specialising `swap()` for certain user-defined types.

Comment: this is cute :) so effectively `break` becomes `throw` and `continue` becomes `return`

Comment: @Fiktik I added another point, which IMHO is the most important

Comment: is it legal to add function overloads into namespace std? I forget what the standard says about this

Comment: @haohaolee good point. It's actually not necessary. I amended my answer.

Comment: It's ok to add template specializations to `namespace std`

Answer (score 7):

Regarding perfomance, your `for` loop calls `std::end` repeatedly, while `std::for_each` will not. This might or might not result in a performance difference depending on the container used.

Comment: Good point. But would it be an issue for any standard container?

Comment: @Andrey: Probably not (IIRC a constant complexity `end` function is a requirement for all STL containers, although I'm not entirely sure of the newer ones). They're typically not no-ops however, so the difference might be measurable with a very simple loop body.

Comment: @Andrey however, your code doesn't have to do that. You can declare and initialize the iterator outside of the loop.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, but maybe citing the standard would make it more valid.

Comment: @Klaim, why do you think so? Do you think that `for` will not evaluate the middle expression repeatedly, or that `for_each` will, for some reason, call `end` (although it doesn't know the container it should call it with)?

Comment: @eq Sorry i misread, i thought you were talking about the for-range loop. Ignore my previous comment. By the way, you could add that the first loop can be written `for (auto it = std::begin(i_container), end_it = std::end(i_container); it != end_it; ++it)` if the call to end() each cycle is not necessary, as it changes it's semantic.

Answer (score 4):

- The `std::for_each` version will visit each element exactly once.  Somebody reading the code can know that as soon as they see `std::for_each`, as there's nothing that can be done in the lambda to mess with the iterator.  In the traditional for loop, you have to study the body of the loop for unusual control flow (`continue`, `break`, `return`) and dinking with the iterator (e.g., in this case, skip the next element with `++it`).
- You can trivially change the algorithm in the lambda solution.  For example, you could make an algorithm that visits every nth element.  In many cases, you didn't really want a for loop anyway, but a different algorithm like `copy_if`.  Using an algorithm+lambda, is often more amenable to change and is a bit more concise.
- On the flip side, programmers are much more used to traditional for loops, so they may find algorithm+lambda to be harder to read.

Comment: *You can trivially change the algorithm in the lambda solution* Could you provide an example which supports this claim? One which is trivial to change in for_each but not trivial in for loop?

Comment: @Andrey:  I did give a couple right in the answer.  I believe Herb Sutter gives more examples in this talk:  http://vimeo.com/23975522

Comment: By "algorithm" he means the looping part, not the body of the loop. An example would be replacing for_each with parallel_for_each.

Answer (score 0):

First, I cannot see much difference between these two, because for_each is implemented using for loop. But note that for_each is a function which has a return value.

Second, I will use range loop syntax once available in this case since this day would come soon anyway.

Comment: The problem with C-style arrays is in the declaration of the lambda. The array doesn't have `typename Container::const_reference`

Comment: Sorry, after a second glance, I realize what you mean...

Comment: You could substitute `decltype(*std::begin(i_container))` for `typename Container::const_reference`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed; in the case of using a Lambda expression, you have to declare the parameter type and name, so nothing is won.

But it will be awesome as soon as you want to call one (named) function or function-object with this. (Remember that you can combine function-like things via `std::bind`.)

The books from Scott Meyers (I believe it was [*Effective STL*](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html)) describe such programming styles very good and clear.